# appending static variable within sql query

Tags: append, static-variables, late-static-binding

I am trying to use the [late static binding concept](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) during insertion but I am getting a syntax error when I am writing this statement:
I am using php version 5.3.8

```
$resultArray = $this->connection->query("insert into " static::$table "(title,link) values('hi','hello')");
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to contain the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot some dots to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) `static::$table` with the rest of the query string. Try this:

```
$resultArray = $this->connection->query("insert into " . static::$table . "(title,link) values('hi','hello')");
```

Comment: no i didn't forget that i tried to use (.) operator but still it is not working

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver CS5  as editor and in that if i am writing this code ,i m facing syntax error indication.....i hope its editor version issue